# converting binary tree to stack without duplicates

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, stack, binary-tree

I have a binary tree of an object type InfoTree the object has 2 properties-number and character, but some characters can repeat themselves.My ultimate goal is to find the object with the character that has the biggest number and return it's character.
for that I have a function to find the maximum number and return in recursively, but I still need to match number with character in a binary tree so I thought of converting the tree to a stack containing only characters but without duplicates here is where I have problems with. My different characters are : k,e,c,d but what I did changes the stack to [k,d,c]-without e and basically doesn't work.

```
//input : The function gets a stack and a character
//output : The function returns true if the character given is in the stack
public static boolean isInStack(Stack<Character> s,char ch){
    while(!s.isEmpty()){
        if(s.pop()==ch)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

 //The function puts all different characters in a stack
public static void stack(BinTreeNode<InfoTree> t,Stack<Character> s){
    s.push(t.getValue().getTav());
    if(t!=null){
        if(t.getLeft()!=null&&t.getRight()!=null){
            if(!isInStack(s,t.getValue().getTav())){
                s.push(t.getValue().getTav());
            }
            stack(t.getLeft(),s);
            stack(t.getRight(),s);
        }
        else if(t.getLeft()!=null)
        {
            if(!isInStack(s,t.getValue().getTav())){
                s.push(t.getValue().getTav());
            }
            stack(t.getLeft(),s);
        }
        else if(t.getRight()!=null)
        {
            if(!isInStack(s,t.getValue().getTav())){
                s.push(t.getValue().getTav());
            }
            stack(t.getRight(),s);
        }
    }
}
```

the tree is :

```
//input : none
//output : The function builds  and returns a tree
public static BinTreeNode<InfoTree> buildtree(){
    BinTreeNode<InfoTree> t1=new BinTreeNode<InfoTree>(new BinTreeNode<InfoTree>(new InfoTree('k',1)),new InfoTree('k',3),new BinTreeNode<InfoTree>(new InfoTree('k',0)));
    t1.getLeft().setLeft(new BinTreeNode<InfoTree>(new InfoTree('k',0)));
    t1.getLeft().setRight(new BinTreeNode<InfoTree>(new InfoTree('k',0)));
    t1.getLeft().getRight().setLeft(new BinTreeNode<InfoTree>(new InfoTree('e',0)));
    t1.getLeft().getRight().getLeft().setRight(new BinTreeNode<InfoTree>(new InfoTree('d',0)));

    t1.getRight().setLeft(new BinTreeNode<InfoTree>(new InfoTree('c',1)));  
    t1.getRight().getLeft().setRight(new BinTreeNode<InfoTree>(new InfoTree('c',0)));
    return t1;
}
```

I'll be really thankful for the help!

Comment: Why do you think a Stack i the correct data structure to find the largest node? Do you know that `stack.pop()` permanently removes the popped element? If you are after the node with the highest value why not traverse the tree keeping tabs on the highest number and node?

Comment: I'm not using a stack to find the highest node, I already have a function to do that recursively as Iv'e mentioned. I want to use the stack to get rid of all duplicates and have easier access to the characters. all I want the function Iv'e showed to do is to return me a stack with all of the tree's different characters. The rest is for another function but if I'll be able to do what I want with the stack I'll know how to continue from there. The reason I chose a stack is simply because I know how to work with it better than I know with a queue or a linked list.

Answer (score 1):

A stack is a horrible data structure for collecting a set. Imagine you have a stack with element A,B,C where  A is the top of stack and in your code you have another C. Your code will stop after popping all of the elements and return `true` that the element was there, but your stack will now have zero elements in it. Was that the last node of the tree that would be the result. That you have 3 out of 4 elements after your run is share luck.

The correct data structure would be a Set:

```
Set<Character> setA = new HashSet<Character>();
setA.add('a');
setA.add('a');
setA.add('b');
setA.add('b');
setA.contains('a'); // ==> true
Character[] result = setA.toArray(new Character[setA.size()]);
```

Basically you don't need to check if you've added it before since it takes care of it. In the end you'll have the unique chars.

Comment: OK thanks! Does that mean the function 'stack' should be working with as long as I don't take out things from the stack-like I did in the function 'isInStack'? I do understand your point  a set would definitely be more efficient only problem is i'm studying java for school and we haven't learned about a set so I don't think my teacher would accept me using it. Is a queue a better data structure for this?at least better than a stack?

Comment: @Karoline  A queue is like a stack but you add to one end and look/get from another. Neither of them works well as a Set since you have no idea if the element is in there or not except the next element out. You'd most likely get lots of duplicates. If you cannot use Set perhaps you should use a collection like a linked list or array instead of Set which basically can be searched before you decide to add. Basically you would be implementing set functionality by other generic data structures.